# C++ WInApi ReadFile reads nothing and reports error 109 ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE

Tags: c++, winapi, readfile, createprocess

I have been trying to call `adb` from a C++ app and read its output, without success. `adb` is present on PATH.

The ReadFile call never reads anything, even if I wait.

`GetLastError()` returns 109 ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE.

I have tried all the solutions proposed in all existing StackOverflow questions on this matter, without any success.

Even trying to capture output from `cmd /c echo Hello World` doesn't work.

Code:

```
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    std::string adbConnectCommand = "adb connect localhost:5555";

    STARTUPINFO startupInfo;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttr;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo;

    HANDLE stdoutReadHandle = NULL;
    HANDLE stdoutWriteHandle = NULL;

    ZeroMemory(&secAttr, sizeof(secAttr));
    secAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    secAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    secAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT
    if (!CreatePipe(&stdoutReadHandle, &stdoutWriteHandle, &secAttr, 0))
        return 2; // error

    // Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited
    if (!SetHandleInformation(stdoutReadHandle, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
        return 2; // error

    ZeroMemory(&startupInfo, sizeof(startupInfo));
    startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
    startupInfo.hStdError = &stdoutWriteHandle;
    startupInfo.hStdOutput = &stdoutWriteHandle;
    startupInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    ZeroMemory(&procInfo, sizeof(procInfo));

    // Start the child process
    if (CreateProcessA(NULL,                // No module name (use command line)
        (TCHAR*)adbConnectCommand.c_str(),  // Command line
        NULL,                               // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,                               // Thread handle not inheritable
        TRUE,                               // Set handle inheritance
        0,                                  // No creation flags
        NULL,                               // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,                               // Use parent's starting directory 
        &startupInfo,                       // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &procInfo)                          // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        )
    {
        // Close the handles we don't need so we can read from stdoutReadHandle
        CloseHandle(procInfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(procInfo.hThread);
        CloseHandle(stdoutWriteHandle);

        std::array<char, 512> buffer;
        std::string adbConnectOutput;

        while(ReadFile(stdoutReadHandle, buffer.data(), buffer.size(), NULL, NULL))
            adbConnectOutput += buffer.data();

        CloseHandle(stdoutReadHandle);

        if (adbConnectOutput.find("connected to localhost:5555") == std::string::npos)
            return 1; // not found

        m_Connected = true;
        return 0; // success
    }

    return 2; // error
}
```

Comment: `#define STRICT` to have the compiler automatically catch the error which Remy found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this code:

> ```cpp
> startupInfo.hStdError = &stdoutWriteHandle;
> startupInfo.hStdOutput = &stdoutWriteHandle;
> ```

`HANDLE` is defined as a `void*`, so any pointer can be assigned to it.  But not every pointer is a valid `HANDLE` value.  In this case, `stdoutWriteHandle` is a `HANDLE` variable and can be assigned as-is to `hStdError` and `hStdOutput`, so you need to drop the `&`s as they don't belong there, eg:

```cpp
startupInfo.hStdError = stdoutWriteHandle;
startupInfo.hStdOutput = stdoutWriteHandle;
```

---

That being said, there are some other problems with your code.

In this code:

> ```
> // Start the child process
> if (CreateProcessA(NULL,                // No module name (use command line)
>     (TCHAR*)adbConnectCommand.c_str(),  // Command line
>     ...
> ```

`TCHAR*` is the wrong type to cast to here. `CreateProcessA()` expects `LPSTR` (aka `char*`) instead, but `TCHAR*` may or may not be `char*` depending on your project configuration.  So use the proper type, eg:

```
CreateProcessA(NULL,
    (LPSTR)adbConnectCommand.c_str(),
    ...
```

However, you should be using the C++-style `const_cast` instead of a C-style cast, eg:

```
CreateProcessA(NULL,
    const_cast<LPSTR>(adbConnectCommand.c_str()),
    ...
```

Alternatively, use `std::string::data()` (C++17 and later) or `std::string::operator[]` instead, eg:

```
CreateProcessA(NULL,
    adbConnectCommand.data(),
    ...
```

```
CreateProcessA(NULL,
    &adbConnectCommand[0],
    ...
```

And, in this code:

> ```
> while(ReadFile(stdoutReadHandle, buffer.data(), buffer.size(), NULL, NULL))
>     adbConnectOutput += buffer.data();
> ```

The data that `ReadFile()` writes to your buffer is not null-terminated, but you are appending a null-terminated `char*` pointer to your output `std::string`.  You need to pay attention to the actual size that `ReadFile()` reports to you, especially since it doesn't require a null terminator, and it may be smaller than what you asked for, eg:

```
std::array<char, 512> buffer;
std::string adbConnectOutput;
DWORD dwNumRead;

while (ReadFile(stdoutReadHandle, buffer.data(), buffer.size(), &dwNumRead, NULL))
    adbConnectOutput.append(buffer.data(), dwNumRead);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick and comprehensive response! The issue is now fixed. For others, the main fix is actually the first part of the response: `startupInfo.hStdError = stdoutWriteHandle;
startupInfo.hStdOutput = stdoutWriteHandle;` (get rid of the references)

Comment: As a side question: I have another case where I don't construct a std::string, but try to directly parse the buffer, with the assumption that the buffer will contain only one line at a time. The issue is that ReadLine always tries to fill its buffer, instead of reading line by line. As far as I understand, the console mode is by default ENABLE_LINE_INPUT, but even by doing `SetConsoleMode(m_processInformation.hProcess, ENABLE_LINE_INPUT)` ReadLine still doesn't stop at the first newline. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: It seems ReadFile will read line by line if I use `cmd` to run the command: `cmd /c adb logcat`. Running `adb` directly will make ReadFile to read as much as it possibly can. The downside of using `cmd` is that it's incredibly slow compared to running `adb` directly. I will implement my own line handling.

Comment: @CosminPolifronie `ReadFile()` reads bytes only, it has no concept of text or lines. So yes, you need your own line handling. Or just use a higher level library that handles lines.

Comment: @CosminPolifronie: Of course `SetConsoleMode(m_processInformation.hProcess, ENABLE_LINE_INPUT)` didn't work.  First, you are running the process in a pipeline, not a console.  Second, you care about the process's output, not its input.